# SQL Server complicated CASE Statement (check value of a field first then choose CASE stmt used)

Tags: sql-server

How would I write a CASE statement where I need to check the value of a field first before I know which way I need the CASE statement prepared? I wrote it as an IF below:

```
select *,
    IF schedule_at is not NULL THEN CASE 
        when actual_start < schedule_at THEN 'Early'
        else 'Late'
        END as Delivery,
    ELSE
        case 
            when actual_start between schedule_from and schedule_to THEN 'On Time'
            when datediff(minute,actual_start,schedule_from) < 0 THEN 'Late'
            else 'Early'
            END as Delivery,
    END
from some_dates_table
```

Comment: in your example, which field are you wanting to check?

Comment: Greg  I am checking if schedule_at is null or not, if it's null I don't want to use that field in the CASE statement, rather I would use TWO other fields schedule_from and schedule_to, If schedule_at is not null then I want to use that field in my CASE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi if i understand what you want this query should be work :

```
select *,
    Case when schedule_at is not NULL THEN (CASE 
        when actual_start < schedule_at THEN 'Early'
        else 'Late'
        END) 
    ELSE
        (case 
            when actual_start between schedule_from and schedule_to THEN 'On Time'
            when datediff(minute,actual_start,schedule_from) < 0 THEN 'Late'
            else 'Early'
            END) END as Delivery
from some_dates_table
```